# Valgrind Comparing pointer with NULL

Tags: c, valgrind

I am using Valgrind to debug my code, and I am getting a warning when I test whether a `struct` is initialized by comparing it with `NULL`.

```
void main()
{
    int *unassignedPointer;
    if(unassignedPointer == NULL)
        printf("This Pointer is NULL\n");
}
```

This code compiles and runs, but when ran through Valgrind it gives a warning: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s). The whole point of comparing it with `NULL` is to determine if it is initialized or not. Is this a dangerous practice, or should I just ignore these warnings?

Comment: *The whole point of comparing it with NULL is to determine if it is initialized or not.*  Huh?!?!  That makes absolutely no sense.  If it's not initialized, comparing it to *anything* is useless.

Comment: This is undefined behavior since the pointer does not have the address of the pointer itself taken. See [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should of course not ignore the warning, you should fix it by initializing the pointer:

```
int *pointer = NULL;
```

in general you cannot detect if a variable has been assigned to, there's no magic "no value" value, all bits of the variable are used to contain the actual value.

Comment: Unclear about the "all bits of the variable are used to contain the actual value" as I do not think pointers are specified to not contain padding.  IAC, that last phrase looks unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

unassignedPointer is an unitialized local variable and reading such variable will lead to undefined behaviour, i.e. you will never know what will happen. On most of the architectures those variables will just contain memory garbage and your code will print nothing or "This pointer is NULL" depending on your luck. You should properly initialize the variable:

```
void main()
{
  int *unassignedPointer = NULL;
  if(unassignedPointer == NULL)
  printf("This Pointer is NULL\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly here

```
int *unassignedPointer; /*here it can points to any unknown memory location */
```

`unassignedPointer` is not initialized and not pointing to valid memory location & dereferencing(if you tried) it causes undefined behavior. your compiler may warn you like

> ‘unassignedPointer’ is used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Werror=uninitialized]

if you compiled your code with proper warning flag like `-Wall` etc. so first initialize `unassignedPointer` with `NULL` like

```
int *unassignedPointer = NULL;
```

*Is this a dangerous practice, or should I just ignore these warnings?* one should never ignore compiler warning. Better compile any simple code with

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c   /* Werror, stops the compilation, convert warning into error */
```

Also read `C` language standard, draft **n1256** section **5.1.2.2.1**

> **Program startup:** It  shall  be  defined  with  a  return  type  of int and  with  no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /*
> ...
> */ }
> ```
>
> or with tw op arameters (referred to here as argc and argv ,though an
>   yn ames may be used, as the ya re local to the function in which the
>   ya re declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*
> ...
> */ }
> ```

This

```
void main() { 
   /*some code */
}
```

is not correct, instead use

```
int main(void) {
    /*some code */
}
```

Comment: "`unassignedPointer` ... &  dereferencing it causes undefined behavior" is true yet OP's code does not dereference `unassignedPointer`.

Comment: Yes true @chux I was just hinting if OP tries to dereference uninitialized pointer, that causes to UB, though OP didn't did in code.

Comment: yes agree @chux dereferencing both  `int *unassignedPointer;` and `int *unassignedPointer = NULL` cause UB.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is uninitialized, that means it wasn't explicitly given an initial value.  That means it could have *any* value, including NULL or some other value.

Formally, an uninitialized variable that does not have static storage duration (i.e. a local variable not marked `static`) has an **indeterminate** value.

Also, as a general rule, warnings in C should *never* be ignored.  The language assumes you know what you're doing and doesn't have any safeguards in place that other language have.